# QT : QListwidget signals when using uo and down arrows

Tags: qt

I have QListwidget object, and I'm using it's signals such as: itemDoubleClicked,itemClicked...

is there a signal for when I use the up/down arrows to go over the QListwidget items?
In general, I want that everytime an item is chosen (through a click/doubleClick/ up&down arrows) to run a function.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the standard should be

```
QListWidget::itemSelectionChanged()
```

and in your function use:

```
QListWidget::selectedItems ()
```

to get the current selection.

Comment: but i dont get the item here.. (the signal doesn't get any parameter)

Comment: Never mind, since when you receive the signal, the selection changed, and you can always get the current selection by calling selectedItems(). If only single selection is enabled, there is only one item in the list returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by installing and implementing an *eventFilter*. 
You can filter every event you waant. Even mouse or keyboard. So you would like to read a little of documentation : [Docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Remember once you have defined an *eventFilter* you have to install it with *installEventFilter* : [installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter)